updateSelectInput not resetting if selection is defined (R Shiny)
Considering the R Shiny code below,
library(shiny)

# Sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "UK", "UK", "UK"),
  State = c("California", "New York", "Texas", "Texas", "Ontario", "Quebec", "British Columbia", "England", "Scotland", "Wales"),
  City = c("Los Angeles", "New York City", "Houston", "San Antonio", "Toronto", "Montreal", "Vancouver", "London", "Edinburgh", "Cardiff")
)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("country", "Select Country", choices = c("", unique(df$Country)), selected = ""),
      selectInput("state", "Select State", choices = NULL, selected = ""),
      selectInput("city", "Select City", choices = NULL, selected = "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Update states based on selected country
  observe({
    req(input$country)
    filtered_states <- unique(df[df$Country == input$country, "State"])
    updateSelectInput(session, "state", choices = c("", filtered_states), selected = "")
  })
  
  # Update cities based on selected state
  observe({
    req(input$country, input$state)
    filtered_cities <- unique(df[df$State == input$state, "City"])
    updateSelectInput(session, "city", choices = c("", filtered_cities), selected = "")
  })
  
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

if an option is selected for any menu, and then the top selection is changed (for country), then the other two menus (state and city) are reset.

However, if the last updateSelectInput is changed as indicated below, the last menu is not reset anymore. Any ideas about how to change the behaviour of the updateSelectInput so it is reset if any of the two menus above is changed?
  # Update cities based on selected state, with a default selection defined
  observe({
    req(input$country, input$state)
    filtered_cities <- unique(df[df$State == input$state, "City"])
    updateSelectInput(session, "city", choices = c("", filtered_cities), selected = filtered_cities[1])
  })



Use observeEvent() instead of observe()

... amd don't conflate the filtering of the underlying data (Country > State > city) with its representation in the UI.  In other words, make filtered_states and filtered_cities reactive.
